# How to loop through rows of Power BI dataset with Python?

Tags: python, powerbi, dataset

I have a dataset in Power BI with the column `randomString`. For example, this dataset looks like this:

```
randomString 
     
helloworld       
teststring
testhello
hihellohi
hihihi
```

I want to loop through the rows of the dataset in the query editor with Python, and check per row whether or not there is a `hello` in the `randomString`. Based on this, the (new) `containsHello` column should be set to `Yes` or `No`. So I want something like this:

```
import re

for row in dataset:
  if re.search(r'hello', str(dataset["randomString"])):
    dataset["containsHello"] = "Yes"
  else:
    dataset["containsHello"] = "No"
```

However, what this code does is check for the word `hello` in the complete `randomString` column. If yes, then all rows get the value `Yes` for `containsHello`, and if not, all rows will get the value `No`. He therefore does not check each row separately for the presence of `hello`, but the entire column at once. So:

```
for row in dataset:
 if re.search(r'hello', str(dataset["randomString"])):
    dataset["containsHello"] = "Yes"
 else:
    dataset["containsHello"] = "No"
```

results in:

```
randomString   containsHello 
     
helloworld     Yes  
teststring     Yes
testhello      Yes
hihellohi      Yes
hihihi         Yes
```

But what I want is:

```
randomString   containsHello 
     
helloworld     Yes  
teststring     No
testhello      Yes
hihellohi      Yes
hihihi         No
```

Could anyone tell me how to loop through each row seperately?

NOTE: It's not a normal dataset in the 'normal' Python, but it's a dataset in Power BI. That will probably make a difference? It's difficult to debug here in Power BI, because you don't have a console to print into.

Comment: In the query editor you can do this natively rather than use Python, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-contains, You can do it in DAX as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/containsstring-function-dax using containsstring, which will evaluate the row and return true/false.

Comment: You are looping through the rows, but then accessing properties on the dataset instead of each row